# Adding touch sensitivity to Grub 2 boot loader?

Tags: ubuntu, touch, bootloader, integrate

I would like to know what libraries exist in Ubuntu 13.04 that would allow integration with Grub2 and more details on it  (i.e. language, development stage, developers, etc.) or if this cannot be done, why?

I also thought it may be possible to use the native device code in the [Surface Pro](https://askubuntu.com/q/265644/88546) architecture but have no experience on how to even start.  If this is possible please let me know, please!

---

**Edit:** March 14, 2013 @ 5:40PM PST

I have been searching hard and have found the following packages under Ubuntu 13.04:

- [muTouch](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/xserver-xorg-input-mutouch/1:1.3.0-1build3)  ( I believe this came from uTouch, an older package that Ubuntu used to use. )
- [libfile-touch-perl](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/libfile-touch-perl/0.08-1)
- [tslib](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/tslib/1.0-11)
- [pymt](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/pymt/0.5.1-0ubuntu3)
- [touchegg](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/touchegg/1.1.1-0ubuntu1)
- [libframe6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/raring/+source/frame/2.5.0daily13.03.12-0ubuntu1)

Comment: Not sure I understand the context. Is it something like in http://linuxaleph.blogspot.ca/2012/06/grub2-usb-keyboard-not-working.html ?

Comment: @Luis Ubuntu 13.04 has a focus n adding touch sensitivity for any touch screen device.  I have already [Achieved loading Grub2](http://askubuntu.com/a/265659/88546) with all of the features and even theme it, but want to add the ability to use touch instead of the keyboard when selecting menu options. Although thanks for the link this may help lead me down the right track.

Comment: Not with Grub2, but I was able to use Window's 10 Windows Boot Manager, which books a minimal kernel that supports Touch.  I used this in place of Grub2, to dual boot my tablet between Windows 10 and ArchLinux.  Reason being: I don't always have a keyboard attached!  It was a PITA as I had to grab the first X bytes from the arch install, stick it in a temp file on the Windows partition, and merge that into the BCD(edit) file manually for Windows Boot Manager to be recognized.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to ask [Stephen Webb](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StephenMWebb) who currently leads the Unity Technical Team about touch input. I contacted him because he used to be the lead developer on the [uTouch-geis](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/utouch-geis) package which was split into three different packages [Frame](https://launchpad.net/frame), [Geis](https://launchpad.net/geis), and [Grail](https://launchpad.net/grail).  These are the primary touch screen controls and he is also heavily involved in other [multi-touch projects](https://launchpad.net/canonical-multitouch). I asked him about learning more about touch device input and my idea.  Here is what he had to say:

---

**I want to have Grub2 register a single tap event, no more (multi touch not needed-I think).  Purpose would be to select from the boot menu.**

> You're going to have a challenge getting touch to work from boot
>   loader code.
>
> Many (but not all) touch input devices have device drivers that work
>   to the Microsoft HID protocol.  You'd need to replicate that driver
>   technology into GRUB2, and then figure out how to map that into
>   something GRUB2 would understand as input.  Sounds like work.

**Is there any resources you can lead me to that would help me understand how touch devices work?**

> That's complicated.  There's a lot of different technologies,
>   connected to the host in different ways, talking different protocols,
>   delivering different data.
>
> There's some good documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/hh852381).

**Are there any single tap libraries you can suggest or multi touch one? Do you have any other suggestions on how to move forward?**

> Well, in the Linux stack there's the firmware in the touch processor,
>   which feeds data to the device driver in the kernel, which translates
>   into the evdev protocol, which is read by the x.org driver and
>   converted into the XI2 protocol, or if there's nothing looking for XI2
>   touch events, then converts *that* into an XI mouse event, and an X11
>   event gets sent to the client.  All you have at the boot loader level
>   is direct input from the touch processor.

---

I asked a varient of this question over at [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/267721/88546) and posted this answer there aswell.